# Differnce between addfirst and offerFirst methods in ArrayDeque

Tags: java, arraydeque

Have tried out a sample program to understand the difference between `addFirst` and `offerFirst` methods in `ArrayDeque` of Java 6. But they seem to be same, any suggestions?

```
public void interfaceDequetest()
{
        try{
        ArrayDeque<String> ad = new ArrayDeque<String>();
        ad.addFirst("a1");
        ad.offerFirst("o1");
        ad.addFirst("a2");
        ad.offerFirst("02");
        ad.addFirst("a3");

        System.out.println("in finally block");

        for (String number : ad){
            System.out.println("Number = " + number);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The difference is what happens when the addition fails, due to a queue capacity restriction:

- `.addFirst()` throws an (unchecked) exception,
- `.offerFirst()` returns `false`.

This is documented in [`Deque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html), which `ArrayDeque` implements.

Of note is that `ArrayDeque` has no capacity restrictions, so basically `.addFirst()` will never throw an exception (and `.offerFirst()` will always return `true`); this is unlike, for instance, a [`LinkedBlockingQueue` built with an initial capacity](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingDeque.html#LinkedBlockingDeque%28int%29).

Answer (score 4):

the source code of offerFirst :

```
 public boolean offerFirst(E e) {
        addFirst(e);
        return true;
    }
```

And addFirst

```
 public void addFirst(E e) {
        if (e == null)
            throw new NullPointerException();
        elements[head = (head - 1) & (elements.length - 1)] = e;
        if (head == tail)
            doubleCapacity();
    }
```

offerFirst returns true, thats the only difference ...